# Visual Studio 2017 fails to install after exactly 5 percent every time...?

Tags: visual-studio

since I have such a big issue with VS 2015 I tried installing 2017. However, this always crashes when it reached 5 percent of the total installaion ( - the upper bar of the two). This is the log that it gives me:

Missing components: 
    .NET-Desktopentwicklung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Entwicklung für die universelle Windows-Plattform (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Mobile-Entwicklung mit .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)

Missing components: 
    .NET Framework 4.6.1-Entwicklungstools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
    .NET-Desktopentwicklungstools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Bild- und 3D-Modell-Editoren (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.0.26208.0)
    C# und Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
    ClickOnce-Veröffentlichung (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Core für die Workload für verwaltete Desktops. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
    Datenquellen und Dienstverweise (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Developer Analytics Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Entity Framework 6-Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.0.26208.0)
    F#-Sprachunterstützung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.0.26208.0)
    JavaScript- und TypeScript-Sprachunterstützung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Just-in-Time-Debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
    NuGet-Paket-Manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Paket zur Festlegung von Zielversionen für die portable .NET-Bibliothek (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Profilerstellungstools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Textvorlagentransformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Tools für Universelle Windows-Plattform (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
    UWP-Tools für Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
    UWP-Tools für Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26424.2)
    Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26228.0)

Package"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator,version=2.2.0.6162404" konnte nicht installiert werden.
    URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2146233033
   Workloads
        .NET-Desktopentwicklung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Entwicklung für die universelle Windows-Plattform (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Mobile-Entwicklung mit .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Components:
        .NET Framework 4.6.1-Entwicklungstools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
        .NET-Desktopentwicklungstools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Bild- und 3D-Modell-Editoren (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.0.26208.0)
        C# und Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
        ClickOnce-Veröffentlichung (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Core für die Workload für verwaltete Desktops. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
        Datenquellen und Dienstverweise (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Developer Analytics Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Entity Framework 6-Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.0.26208.0)
        F#-Sprachunterstützung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.0.26208.0)
        JavaScript- und TypeScript-Sprachunterstützung (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26412.1)
        Just-in-Time-Debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
        NuGet-Paket-Manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Paket zur Festlegung von Zielversionen für die portable .NET-Bibliothek (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Profilerstellungstools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Textvorlagentransformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Tools für Universelle Windows-Plattform (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26412.1)
        UWP-Tools für Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
        UWP-Tools für Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26424.2)
        Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Protokoll
        C:\Users\Julius1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170622113019_080_Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.log
    Details
        Code -2146233033
        Codedetails ausgeben: The comporessed part is inconsistent in length.

Is this helpful? If you need any other info, just ask. I hope we can sort this out! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Okay everybody - it looks like i found the problem's solution:

1. Downloading this tool here: 
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed
2. Deinstalling EVERYTHING in this list that is listed with VISUAL STUDIO 2017. ( In my case, this was only one file)
3. Deleting the whole "Visual Studio 2017" folder on C:\Progs\
4. Installing again.

Hope this will help others in the future!